# How Does One Change The Meta-Description Of Home-Page?

Tags: theme-development, seo

In WordPress, How Does One Change The Meta-Description Of The Home-Page?

Honestly, I have searched low and high for the answer to this in WordPress. Went to every page in the back-office to no avail.

In Google search results it repeats my company slogan twice and that is all. Nobody will click on this as it looks ridiculous. How and where do I change this?

It is an Arras Theme, if that helps

Comment: Is the home page an actual page or is it the default listing of posts? If it's a page, is it using a page template? Let us know - perhaps we can provide some insight based on how the sit eis setup.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than editing and hard coding into your templates, you should use a plugin such as http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ which will give you the option to edit meta tags for each of your pages including the home page.

Answer (score 1):

In your header.php file:

```
if ( is_home() ) { ?>
    <meta name="description" content="Your home page meta description" />
<?php } else {  ?>  <meta name="description" content="Your none homepage meta description" /> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: In reply to @tom's question, an alternative would be to use `if ( is_home() OR is_front_page() ) { ?>
`

Answer (score -1):

The Yoast SEO plugin does have an option for home meta description.