# Change The Meta-Description Of Home-Page?

Tags: theme-development, seo

I would like to use this script ([found here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42739/how-does-one-change-the-meta-description-of-home-page)), but it generates a blank page when I add it to my header.php

```
     if ( is_home() ) { ?>
    <meta name="description" content="Your home page meta description" />
<?php } else {  ?>  <meta name="description" content="Your none homepage meta description" /> 
<?php } ?>
```

Thank's!

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: You are using an opening PHP tag, right? That is `<?php if ( is_home() )` etc

Comment: Ok, yes indeed I forgot <? php! But I thought this script was the description that on the home page, off it appears on all pages. How can make for the description is displayed right on the home page? Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it with this code and it all worked as it should:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
    <meta name="description" content="Your home page meta description" />
<?php else : ?>
    <meta name="description" content="Your non-homepage meta description" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

You want to be sure there's not a space between `<?` and `php` (`<?php`).